# Proper syntax URL parameter datastore file GeoServer

Tags: postgis, geoserver, datastore

I am trying to set up the URL parameter for connecting to a PostGIS database created in AWS, and I'm struggling to set up what comes after the 'jdbc' expression.

My datastore.properties file looks like this:

```
user=admin
port=5432
passwd=pwd
url=jdbc\:**???**\:**???**
host=mydbserver.123456789012.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com
database=test_database
driver=org.postgresql.Driver
schema=schema_name
SPI=org.geotools.data.postgis.PostgisNGDataStoreFactory
Loose\ bbox=true
Expose\ primary\ key=false
Max\ open\ prepared\ statements=50
preparedStatements=false
Estimated\ extends=false
max\ connections=20
min\ connections=5
fetch\ size=1000
```

According to this: [PostgisNGDataStoreFactory](https://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/geotools/data/postgis/PostgisNGDataStoreFactory.html), after the JDBC expression one should append the HOST followed by the   DATABASE, but it is not clear to me because there is already a parameter called host and another called database.

I would like to understand it, rather than start trying multitude of combinations until it works.

Comment: I can't be sure without checking the code but I don't think it's used If the host etc is present. Easiest way to check is to set one up using the GUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the [manual](https://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/jdbc/postgis.html) the URL parameter is not mentioned:

> Parameter Description
>
> dbtype:    Must be the string postgis
>
> host:      Machine name or IP address to connect to
>
> port:      Port number to connect to, default 5432
>
> schema:    The database schema to access
>
> database:  The database to connect to
>
> user:      User name
>
> passwd:    Password